# How can I make a webhook in plotly dash?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, webhooks, plotly-dash, aws-iot

Anyone know how to make a webhook in Plotly Dash in Python? I have a Flask website that uses Dash to make a single page application using React behind the scenes.

The Dash page sets a process in motion, and that process lets the world know it's finished by putting a value into an AWS IoT device shadow. How can my Dash/Flask page subscribe to a webhook/callback for when that AWS IoT device shadow sees a certain value? At that time, I'd like to update the website user that the process is finished.

I hear Flask has a "Signals" package for webhooks, but it's not clear to me that I'm starting in the right place. Any advice/examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative might be Dash intervals

https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

This would be "polling" rather than a webhook, I suppose, but it would get the job done. Every few seconds I could check the AWS device shadow using an interval in Dash